# How to name a form in symfony2?

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I've got the following code to create a form in symfony2.

```
private function createDeleteForm($id)
{
    return $this->createFormBuilder()
        ->setAction($this->generateUrl('anne_stage_delete', array('id' => $id)))
        ->setMethod('DELETE')
        ->add('delete', 'submit')
        ->getForm()
    ;
}
```

But I can't find out how to add/change the name attribute. When I look in the rendered html the form name is `form`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the form name in twig

```
<form action="{{ path('yourpath') }}" method="post" name="your_name-form">
{{ form_widget(form) }}
</form>
```

Or

You can use **createNamedBuilder**

```
$form = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamedBuilder('your-custom-name', 'form',  null, array(
    'constraints' => $collectionConstraint,
))
->add('delete', 'submit')
->getForm();
```